# Launcher "Failed to execute child process (No such file or directory)"

Tags: debian, java, xfce, launcher

I installed the Oracle JDK and it is working correctly.  The `$PATH` variable is correctly configured so that it points to the `jdk/bin` directory and all the executables run correctly.

The problem comes when I try to use a launcher to run any of them.  I have tried to copy the launcher from the `jdk/jre/lib/desktop/applications` directory into `/usr/share/applications` and making a custom launcher with Menulibre, but none of them work.

Whenever I try to run the launcher, I get an error which reads

```
Failed to execute file "JavaWS"
Failed to execute child process "javaws" (No such file or directory).
```

Additionally, the launcher does not show up in the applications menu or the Open With dialogue, but I suspect this is only a symptom of the other issue and not a separate problem.

I have verified that javaws is in a directory listed in the `$PATH` variable, and it works when I call it from the terminal without the launcher.

I am running Debian Jessie with XFCE4.

I would greatly appreciate any help in getting the launcher to work.

Comment: I would try setting JAVA_HOME to the JDK dir

Comment: @mt025 JAVA_HOME is set to the JDK directory.  JAVA_HOME/bin is appended to the end of PATH as well.